# purpose of bamf-2.index

Tags: bash, filesystem, files

What is the purpose of `/usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index` ?

I have noticed the applications it contains are installed in my computer. But I don't think it contains the complete list. Because the following commands give different values

```
more /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index| wc -l  
dpkg-query -l | wc -l`
```

Please Explain.

Comment: It is used by `bamfdaemon` ....

Comment: Thanks. **bamf** matches application windows to desktop files, and **bamf-2.index** contains this information.